# Python edge detection of a fairly dark image with low contrast

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing, edge-detection

My aim is to detect all the contours, then run a circular Hough transform on them, to detect the circles on them and display them on the base image, then follow up with other actions. I should point out that my Hough transform was done only with the Numpy library and without any image processing or computer vision libraries, and it works perfectly.  But the first step is still to do the edge detection, for which I first tried to do it without a computer vision library either (only numpy and matplotlib) using the image gradient and the Sobel filter, which worked with my test images but not with those that matter most to me. I then used openCV's Canny function for edge detection, and added several morphological operations, but the result is still not there. So I'm asking for your help so that I can move forward, even if I have to read a lot of articles, forums, etc... It wasn't working. I've tried everything from changing to testing thresholds by hysteresis but still nothing better, the image I've posted of the edge detection is my best result yet.

Thank you for your help,

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import cv2

def detection_contours(image):
    if len(image.shape) == 3 and image.shape[2] == 3:
        gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    else:
        gray = image

    brightness = 10
    contrast = 5
    out = cv2.addWeighted(img, contrast, img, 0, brightness)

    # Égalisation d'histogramme
    gray_eq = cv2.equalizeHist(out)

    # Définition de l'opération de morphologie
    operation = cv2.MORPH_DILATE

    # Définition du noyau
    kernel_size = (3, 3)
    kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, kernel_size)

    # Application de l'opération de morphologie
    gradient = cv2.morphologyEx(gray_eq, operation, kernel)
    edges = np.zeros_like(gradient, dtype=np.uint8)
    blurred = cv2.medianBlur(gradient, 9)
    edges = cv2.Canny(gradient, 0, 200)

    return edges

img = plt.imread("manip0.jpg")
#img_redim = cv2.resize(img, (0, 0), fx = 0.1, fy = 0.1)
plt.imshow(img, cmap='gray')
plt.axis('off')
plt.show()

contours = detection_contours(img)
plt.imshow(contours, cmap='gray')
plt.axis('off')
plt.show()
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xootl.jpg)

That's the image i want to process.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fmJIg.jpg)

The result i have..

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w37fY.jpg)

And this after my Hough Transform, the first circle is the good one, the second is the bad one, I want to detect the circle that represents the contour of the lens.

Thank you for your future help !

Comment: You are looking for two co-centric circle. You can use that as constraint when selecting circles from hough transform. This way you can remove the circle detected from shadow in your result. However, before you do that, you mentioned `the first circle is the good one`. How is your first circle good one. Your first image has an artificial black circle and that is what is detected, not the center of camera. What is that artificial black circle/sticker?

Comment: @saurabheights Thank you very much for your answer, my system consists of a camera that I place inside my photometer, all facing the mirror (the image I've sent), the black circle is only the sighting pattern of the photometer, only now I'd like it to also detect the contour of the lens, to subsequently create autocollimation. I'll try what you told me, but I don't think that's the point, the point is to have 2 circles, then with an optimization technique align them to create this autocollimation.

Comment: Is your second link thr result of your function (canny after morph)? Where's your hough code? OpenCV HoughCirclr doesnt work well on edge masks, but you dont use opencv hough, right?

Comment: @Micka thanks for your answer, nop I dont use the Hough function of OpenCV, but my own HoughCircle work well on edge masks, that's why i want to improve my edge detection

Comment: First thing that I would do is to increase the contrast using skimage.exposure.rescale_intensity().

Comment: any other help?